# Can you show only specific Desktop Icons on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, desktop

I would like to know if there is a way to show only specific desktop icons on the Windows desktop? I usually keep a clean wallpaper look by not showing any icons by right clicking on ***Desktop*** > ***View*** > Uncheck ***Show Desktop Icons***. But, I do like to have one or two icons show up.

[image: hide desktop icons]

My desktop has many application icons and other things. When I enable ***Show Desktop Icon***, those are the ones I need. So, I do not want to move them all to some folder to "cleanup" my desktop.

I am just looking for a way to selectively show desktop icons while keeping all other icons hidden and intact.

Comment: There is no simple way to do this. It is all or nothing. If you really want this functionality you can probably find software that enhances the desktop with features like that, like "Stardock Fences"

Comment: Stardock [Fences](https://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) is the way to go for this functionality